# Solve the following limit?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

Please only give hints? $$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{6}}\frac{2\sin{(x)}-1}{\sqrt{3}\tan{(x)}-1}$$ I tried this and I was able to simplify it down to $$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{6}}\frac{\sin{(2x)}-\cos{(x)}}{2\sin{(x - \frac{\pi}{6})}}.$$ However, I am stuck here and I don't even know if this is the right approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F=\frac{2\sin{(x)}-1}{\sqrt{3}\tan{(x)}-1} =\frac2{\sqrt3}\cdot\frac{\sin x-\sin \frac\pi6}{\tan x-\tan\frac\pi6} =\frac2{\sqrt3}\cdot\frac{2\sin \left(\frac{x-\frac\pi6}2\right)\cos  \left(\frac{x+\frac\pi6}2\right)}{\tan x-\tan\frac\pi6}$$ (Applying $\sin C-\sin D=2\sin\frac{C-D}2\cos\frac{C+D}2$)

Now, $$\tan x-\tan\frac\pi6 =\frac{\sin \left(x-\frac\pi6\right)}{\cos x\cos\frac\pi6}=\frac{2\sin \left(\frac{x-\frac\pi6}2\right)\cos\left(\frac{x-\frac\pi6}2\right)}{\cos x\cos\frac\pi6}$$

So, $$F=\frac2{\sqrt3} \cos x\cos\frac\pi6\frac{2\sin \left(\frac{x-\frac\pi6}2\right)\cos\left(\frac{x+\frac\pi6}2\right)}{2\sin \left(\frac{x-\frac\pi6}2\right)\cos\left(\frac{x-\frac\pi6}2\right)}$$

If $x\to\frac\pi6, \sin \left(\frac{x-\frac\pi6}2\right)\to0\implies \sin \left(\frac{x-\frac\pi6}2\right)\ne0$

So, $$\lim_{x\to\frac\pi6}F=\lim_{x\to\frac\pi6}\frac2{\sqrt3} \cos x\cos\frac\pi6\frac{\cos\left(\frac{x+\frac\pi6}2\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{x-\frac\pi6}2\right)}=\frac2{\sqrt3} \cos \frac\pi6\cos\frac\pi6 \frac{\cos\frac\pi6}{\cos0}=\frac34$$

Comment: Thanks, very nice solution. How did you come up with this tho? How did you know that this complex sequence of steps would lead you to the answer? Did it take you a long time?

Comment: @Ovi, I've observed the Singularity at $x=\frac\pi6\implies  \sin \left(\frac{x-\frac\pi6}2\right)=0$ there. Please find my other answer.Hope that is simpler.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $\sin(2x)=2\sin x \cos x$

Comment: Haha more hints please?

Comment: I don't see how this really helps

Comment: Yea the only thing you can do after that is factor out the cos(x) but I don't see how that helps

Answer (score 4):

Another hint: Try using L'Hôpital's rule. If you plug $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{6}$ into the original limit, you'll see that it evaluates to an indeterminate $\displaystyle \frac{0}{0}$. Use that and the rule, and you should be able to solve for the limit.

Comment: Is there really no other way?

Comment: Well, this is one of the simpler methods. I suppose you could try reorganizing the limit...

Comment: Well yea I'm trying to do that but I'm kindda stuck.

Comment: Which part? Do you need some help with the differentiation steps for the top and bottom parts?

Comment: No I meant I was trying to reorganize the limit and solve it without L'Hopital's rule

Comment: Ah I see. It also seems that you had your original question answered. I hope you found the conversation informative.

Comment: Yes thanks but can you please take a look at user17762's answer? I thought that it just simplified to the derivative of sin (x) at x=pi/6 over the derivative of tan(x) at x=pi/6. However, this gives you 3sqrt(3)/8, and the correct answer is supposed to be 3/4.

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$\dfrac{2 \sin(x)-1}{\sqrt3 \tan(x) - 1} = \dfrac2{\sqrt3} \left(\dfrac{\sin(x)-1/2}{\tan(x)-1/\sqrt{3}} \right) = \dfrac2{\sqrt3} \dfrac{\dfrac{\sin(x)-\sin(\pi/6)}{x-\pi/6}}{\dfrac{\tan(x)-\tan(\pi/6)}{x-\pi/6}}$$

Comment: Oh thanks I see so now it's just the derivative of sin x at pi/6 over the derivative of the tangent. Thanks

Comment: Wait I thought that it would just be $cos(pi/6)/sec^2(pi/6)$. However, this gives you 3sqrt(3)/8, and the correct answer is 3/4.

Comment: @Ovi There is a $\dfrac2{\sqrt3}$ multiplying it.

Comment: Haha ok thanks I completely missed that

Answer (score 2):

Hint: L'Hopital's Rule right at the beginning

Comment: Is there really no other way?

Answer (score 0):

Putting $x=\frac\pi6-y$ as $x\to\frac\pi6,y\to0$

$$2\sin x-1=2\sin(\frac\pi6-y)-1=\cos y-\sqrt3\sin y-1$$

$$\sqrt3\tan x-1=\sqrt3\tan(\frac\pi6-y)-1=\sqrt3\cdot \frac{\frac1{\sqrt3}-\tan y}{1+\tan y\frac1{\sqrt3}}-1$$
$$=\sqrt3\cdot\frac{1-\sqrt3\tan y}{\sqrt3+\tan y}-1=\frac{\sqrt3-3\tan y}{\sqrt3+\tan y}-1=\frac{-4\tan y}{\sqrt3+\tan y}$$

$$\text{So,}\frac{2\sin x-1}{\sqrt3\tan x-1}=\frac{(\cos y-\sqrt3\sin y-1)(\sqrt3+\tan y)}{-4\tan y}$$
$$=\frac14\cdot(\sqrt3+\tan y)\cdot\left(\sqrt3\frac{\sin y}{\tan y}+\frac{1-\cos y}{\tan y} \right)$$

$$\text{So,}\lim_{x\to\frac\pi6}\frac{2\sin x-1}{\sqrt3\tan x-1}$$

$$=\lim_{y\to0}\frac14\cdot(\sqrt3+\tan y)\cdot\left(\sqrt3\frac{\sin y}{\tan y}+\frac{1-\cos y}{\tan y} \right)$$

$$= \frac14\cdot\lim_{y\to0}(\sqrt3+\tan y)\cdot\left(\sqrt3 \cdot\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\sin y}{\tan y}+\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\sin^2y\cdot\cos y}{\sin y(1+\cos y)} \right)$$
$$=\frac14\cdot(\sqrt3+0)\cdot\left(\lim_{y\to0}\sqrt3\cos y+\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\sin y\cdot\cos y}{1+\cos y} \right)$$ as $y\to0,\sin y\to 0\implies \sin y\ne0$

$$=\frac{\sqrt3}4\cdot(\sqrt3+0)$$

Comment: @Ovi, is this simpler than my other answer?